# how to redirect the output of python code to a file

Tags: python

How to write the output of python code to a file inside the same python script

```
# Reading an excel file using Python 
import xlrd 

# Give the location of the file 
 loc = ("C:\\Users\\212515181\\Desktop\\Dual_Mode_cfgctrl.xlsx") 

# To open Workbook 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

#  Getting Root record value  
print("ROOT,"+  '"CONFIGMDL"')

# Getting Comput record entries

for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
 if sheet.cell_value(k,2)=="COMPUT" and sheet.cell_value(k,0)!="#":
  print ('\n')
  print("COMPUT,",end='')
  for i in range (4,14,2):
      print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')

# Getting Direct record entries

for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
 if sheet.cell_value(k,2)=="DIRECT" and sheet.cell_value(k,0)!="#":
  print ('\n')
  print("DIRECT,",end='')
   for i in range (4,14,2):      
    print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')      


# Getting Disk record entries

for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
 if sheet.cell_value(k,2)=="DISK" and sheet.cell_value(k,0)!="#":
  print ('\n')
  print("DISK,",end='')
  for i in range (4,22,2):      
    print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')      

# Getting Domain record entries

for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
 if sheet.cell_value(k,2)=="DOMAIN" and sheet.cell_value(k,0)!="#":
  print ('\n')
  print("DOMAIN,",end='')
   for i in range (4,12,2):      
    print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')  

# Getting Equipments record entries

for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
 if sheet.cell_value(k,2)=="EQUIP" and sheet.cell_value(k,0)!="#":
  print ('\n')
  print("EQUIP,",end='')
   for i in range (4,20,2):      
    print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')

# Getting Local system record entries

for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
 if sheet.cell_value(k,2)=="LOCSYS" and sheet.cell_value(k,0)!="#":
  print ('\n')
  print("LOCSYS,",end='')
   for i in range (4,10,2):      
    print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')      

# Getting Appset record entries

for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
 if sheet.cell_value(k,2)=="APPSET" and sheet.cell_value(k,0)!="#":
  print ('\n')
  print("APPSET,",end='')
   for i in range (4,18,2):      
    print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')

# Getting Dbsset record entries

for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
 if sheet.cell_value(k,2)=="DBSSET" and sheet.cell_value(k,0)!="#":
   print ('\n')
   print("DBSSET,",end='')
  for i in range (4,14,2):      
    print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')      

# Getting Process record entries

for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
 if sheet.cell_value(k,2)=="PRCESS" and sheet.cell_value(k,0)!="#":
  print ('\n')
  print("PRCESS,",end='')
   for i in range (4,12,2):      
    print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')      

# Getting Taskset record entries

 for k in range(2,sheet.nrows):
  if sheet.cell_value(k,2)=="TSKSET" and sheet.cell_value(k,0)!="#":
   print ('\n')
   print("TSKSET,",end='')
    for i in range (4,10,2):      
     print('"%s"' % sheet.cell_value(k,i),",",end='',sep='')
```

My Current output is :

> ROOT,"CONFIGMDL"
>
> COMPUT,"USADS1","T","F","F","60",
>
> COMPUT,"USADS2","T","F","F","60",
>
> DIRECT,"EMSA","1","30","10","60",
>
> DIRECT,"EMSB","2","30","10","60",
>
> DISK,"EMSA_C","C:","System","F","F","0","0","75","95",
>
> DISK,"EMSA_D","D:","Data","F","F","0","0","75","95",
>
> DOMAIN,"HOST","60","T","F",
>
> EQUIP,"USADS1","3.0","","","T","F","","",
>
> LOCSYS,"EMSB","2","T",
>
> APPSET,"EMSHOST","EMSHOST","EMSA SERVER","1","T","F","T",
>
> DBSSET,"EMSHOST","0","60","1","1",
>
> PRCESS,"MRS","T","F","1",
>
> PRCESS,"CFGMONI","T","F","1",
>
> PRCESS,"CFGPING","T","F","1",
>
> PRCESS,"PROCMAN","F","T","",
>
> TSKSET,"EMSHOST","1","1",

My Requirement is to this output to a file without any empty lines. Please help me guys I am new to python.

My input excel is here:

[image: input excel]

Comment: It’s not necessary to “redirect” anything if it’s your script: just open the file.

Comment: Hello Davis, thanks for replying me. Actually I want the output file to import in my other application database. Please help I want to save the output of this code in a text file.

Comment: II you don't want to edit the script, just redirect the output. Doing this is not related to python but to your system. For example, if you use linux and call your script from bash, just type: `python my_script.py > outfile.txt` Anything which is usually printed in the console now is written inside `outfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globally you can use (with Python 3.0 or later)

```
from sys import stdout
stdout = open("logfilepath", "w")

print("output")
```

For individual print statements you can use (with Python 2.5 or later)

```
log = open("logfilepath", "w")

print >> log, "output"
```

Just make sure to call `close()` when you are done writing output. Alternatively you can write the output directly to the file, as the comment from @Davis Herring hinted,

```
log = open("logfilepath", "w")

log.write("output")
```

which will also require a call to `close()` when you are done writing output.

Comment: There’s also Python 3’s `print(…,file=…)`.

Comment: Thanks Davis and William, got it very clearly. Thanks